# How to deal with a breaking change in an invariant (business rule) when you expose a Public API

Tags: api, domain-driven-design

I am starting to investigate the good practices about Public API, specifically about how to deal with breaking changes. There is a lot of technicalities related to the versioning (or non-versioning!), but I am more interested about the code base implication.

Imagine a basic scenario where you have a business rule "password must have at least 10 caracters". And you have a "Create User" scenario exposed in a public API, accepting a password.

You have hundreds of clients using it, and one day, you decide to change the business rule to "password must have at least 15 caracters". Even if you did not change the semantic of the API signature and payloads, you just introduced a breaking change in your API because you changed the behavior of this API.

How would you deal with this?

I only find wrong approaches:

1. Modify your domain invariants (business rules) with dated/versionned invariants: this would create a nightmare in the code readibility / testing / etc.
2. Duplicate your code base per API version: this would create a maintenance nightmare
3. Hope one day you will be able to deprecate all this and become clean again: in your dream...

Any real life experience on this in your job?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to communicate with your clients and warn them of the upcoming change weeks/months before. This way they can prepare and be ready for the breaking change.

If you absolutely must support old clients, another option is to keep the domain invariant to 10, but add an additionnal api call for the create user scenario which checks the password length and verifies it is of length 15 outside the domain. Then, encourage your users to migrate to the new CreateUser endpoint. This works for simple cases like this one but will become very hard to do for complicated invariants or if your domain is used in different contexts (multiple Apis, desktop app etc).

If you decide to go with this route, a good tip is to make sure you have metrics to know how many clients use the old endpoint vs how many use the new endpoint. When you have reached a certain threshold you can shutdown the old endpoint and move the minimum password length of 15 invariant from the Api to the domain,